# Classify values on ranges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an enumeration as follows:

```
public enum BPLevel {
  Normal = 1,
  HighNormal = 2,
  HypertensionStage1 = 3,
  ModerateHypertensionStage2 = 4,
  SeverHypertensionStage3 = 5,
} // BloodPressureLevel
```

And I have the following classification:

[image: Classification table]

I am using Entity Framework and I need count how many persons are in each level:

```
IDictionary<BPLevel, Int32> stats = context
  .Persons
  .Select(x => new { PersonId = x.Person.Id, BPDiastolic = x.BPDiastolic, BPSystolic = x.BPSystolic })
  .Count( ...
```

My problem is how can I apply this classification in my query?

Comment: Can you post the class members of `context.Persons`?

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a classification member that is assigned to the result of a function call

```
IDictionary<BPLevel, Int32> stats = context
  .Persons
  .Select(x => new { PersonId = x.Person.Id, BPDiastolic = x.BPDiastolic, 
                     BPSystolic = x.BPSystolic, 
                     Classification = GetClassification(BPDiastolic, BPSystolic) })
  .Count( ...

BPLevel GetClassification(int diastolic, int systolic)
{
    ...
}
```

Queries to EF sometimes don't like operations happening inside the queries, so you may need to do a `ToList` before the `Select` to get it into memory (so its LINQ to objects).

Comment: I would be happy to hear from the downvoter what problem they have with my approach/post.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a private static helper function in your class that does the classification for you and insert a call to that function in your projection.  Something like:

```
private static BPLevel ClassifyBP(int diastolic, int systolic) {
  // Appropriate switch statement here
}
```

and then your Select projection looks like:

```
.Select(x => new { PersonId = x.Person.Id,
                   BPDiastolic = x.BPDiastolic, 
                   BPSystolic = x.BPSystolic, 
                   BPLevel = ClassifyBP(x.BPDiastolic, x.BPSystolic) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) statement would allow you to classify everyone into their respective `BPLevel`, which which point you merely need to perform a [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.100).aspx) and count the people in each category. Thus

```
IDictionary<BPLevel, Int32> stats = context
  .Persons
  .Select(x => new { PersonId = x.Person.Id, BPDiastolic = x.BPDiastolic, BPSystolic = x.BPSystolic })
  .AsEnumerable()  // I'm not completely familiar with Entity Framework, so this line may be necessary to force evaluation to continue in-memory from this point forward
  .GroupBy(p => ... // Test which returns a BPLevel)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do in this case, is make a helper property in `Person`

```
public BPLevel BpLevel 
{
    get
    {
        if(Systolic >= 180)
            return BPLevel.SeverHypertensionStage3
        else if
           ...
    }
}
```

and then I'd do a group by

```
.ToList()   // you need to execute against the DB before you call the helper property
.GroupBy(x => x.BPLevel) 
.Select(x => /*moar data transformation
               x is a collection of Person
               x.Key, is the BPLevel*/ )
```

Make sure that you do that `ToList()` part, or else you might get a not supported exception when it tries to convert your helper property to SQL

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to Select into a concrete class that has a BPLevel property getter that does the classification for you:

```
public class PersonWithBP {

  // other properties

  public BPLevel BPClassification {
    get { 
      // logic to calculate BPLevel
      return bpLevel;
   }

}
```

Now your select becomes

```
.Select(x => new PersonWithBP() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty, but the count query will be executed in database.

```
var stats = context.Persons
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Level = x.BPDiastolic < 85 && x.BPSystolic < 130
            ? BPLevel.Normal
            : (x.BPDiastolic < 90 && x.BPSystolic < 140
                ? BPLevel.HighNormal
                : (x.BPDiastolic < 100 && x.BPSystolic < 160
                    ? BPLevel.HypertensionStage1)
                    : (x.BPDiastolic < 110 && x.BPSystolic < 180
                        ? BPLevel.ModerateHypertensionStage2
                        : BPLevel.SeverHypertensionStage3)))

    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Level)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, g => g.Count()) // execute in database
    .Union(Enum.GetValues(typeof(BPLevel))
        .OfType<BPLevel>()
        .ToDictionary(x => x, x => 0)) // default empty level
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => y.Value)); // combine both
```